# Current meter doesn't short a circuit?

Tags: current-measurement, opto-isolator, current-limiting

I have a control card where two pins can be shorted with a push button to trigger an action (5V can be measured between the two pins.)

- If I briefly short the pins with a jumper, the action is triggered as expected
- If I short the pins with a current-meter: nothing happens. By that I mean that I'm trying to measure the current between the two pins. I would expect the current meter to short the circuit, trigger a current and measure it.

My question: is that because the current-meter has too big of an internal resistance, or is it something else ? I reckon the approach is pretty naive but it got me curious now.

Background of why I'm doing this: I intend to remotely control the action using an Arduino. My idea is to use an optocoupler that acts as a push button (and keep both circuits isolated.) Then I wondered if I would need a resistor to avoid frying the optocoupler's transistor so I tried to measure a current. Apparently it doesn't work.

Also, should I be worried that my optocoupler will also have too big of a resistance to make the circuit work?

EDIT: I feel very stupid, but I think my multimeter is simply broken :/
It does measure voltages, but setting it to current even fails to measure a current through a simple resistor.

Comment: How did you use the current meter? What kind of meter is it? Is it a multimeter, set to current measurement mode, leads moved to correct current measurement socket and fuse is know to be good?

Comment: Multimeter, set to current measurement. I started with highest values, then lowered the calibration. I guess I could check that the multimeter works. At least it works for voltage measurement

Comment: What current the did the multimeter show when you did the measurement?

Comment: Multimeter always shows 0

Comment: Thanks @Justme you were right: the fuse of the multimeter is indeed the issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel stupid but I think my multimeter was simply broken :/
Trying to measure a current through a resistor also failed. The fact that it still measures voltages (with proper settings of course) got me confused.

Comment: If it is only the fuse, it does not mean the multimeter is broken.

Comment: True. I'll change the fuse and try again :)